# How to select a row in gridview by code based on its key value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net web forms application to view data of certain table in grid view & select a row in this grid view based on ID of this data row (Key Value) retrieved from query string
I tried using this code in Code behind

```
gridview1.SelectedValue= Request.QueryString["RowToSelectID"];
```

but it said that selected value is a read only property and can't be assigned 
Is there another way to do that ?

Comment: did you try the `SelectedIndex` property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following and see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

```
var keyValue = 1; // Replace with your Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RowToSelectID"])
 for (int i = 0; i <= this.gridview1.DataKeys.Count - 1; i++)
 {
   if ((int)gridview1.DataKeys[i].Value == keyValue )
    {
       this.gridview1.SelectedIndex = i;
   }
}
```

I used the **SelectedIndex**. The record in the GridView having a key value of **1**, will be selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot; Great answer but Is there something like that in DetailsView ?

Comment: Optimization suggestion: You can add a `break` to the end of your `if` block to prevent iterating over the rest of the data keys when a match is found, which can be helpful if there's thousands of records in your GridView.